# How to create @RabbitListener to be idempotent

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

Our configuration is: 1...n Message receivers with a shared database.
Messages should only be processed once.

```
   @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = "message-queue", durable = "true"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = TOPIC_EXCHANGE, type = "topic", durable = "true"),
            key = MESSAGE_QUEUE1_RK)
    )
    public void receiveMessage(CustomMessage message) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("I have been received = " + message);
    }
```

We want to to guarantee messages will be processed once, we have a message store with id's of messages already processed. 
Is it possible to hook in this check before receiveMessage?
We tried to look at a MessagePostProcessor with a rabbitTemplate but didn't seem to work.

any advice on how to do this?
We tried with a MethodInterceptor and this works, but is pretty ugly.
Thanks

---

Solution found - thanks to Gary
I created a `MessagePostProcessorInjector` which implements `SmartLifecycle`
and on startup, I inspect each container and if it is a `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` add a customer `MessagePostProccesser`
and a custom `ErrorHandler` which looks for certain type of Exceptions and drops them (other forward to defaultErrorHandler) 
Since we are using DLQ I found throwing exceptions or setting to null wouldn't really work.

I'll make a pull request to ignore null Messages after a MPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting; the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` does have a property `afterReceivePostProcessors` (<s>not currently available via the listener container factory used by the annotation, but it could be injected later</s>).

However, those postprocessors won't help because we still invoke the listener.

Please feel free to open a [JIRA Improvement Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) for two things:

1. <s>expose the `afterReceivePostProcessors` in the listener container factories</s>
2. if a post processor returns null, skip calling the listener method.

(correction, the property is indeed exposed by the factory).

**EDIT**

How it works...

During context initialization...

1. For each annotation detected by the bean post processor the container is created and registered in the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry`
2. Near the end of context initialization, the registry is `start()`ed and it starts all containers that are configured for `autoStartup` (default).

To do further configuration of the container before it's started (e.g. for properties not currently exposed by the container factories), set `autoStartup` to `false`.

You can then get the container(s) from the registry (either as a collection or by `id`). Simply `@Autowire` the registry in your app.

Cast the container to a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` (or alternatively a `DirectMessageListenerContainer` if using Spring AMQP 2.0 or later and you are using its factory instead).

Set the additional properties (such as the `afterReceiveMessagePostProcessors`); then `start()` the container.

Note: until we enhance the container to allow MPPs that return `null`, a possible alternative is to throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` from the MPP. However, this is probably not what you want if you have DLQs configured.

Comment: Thanks Gary, can you provide any information about how the Annotation hangs together ? What stage does the factory create the container - is there any way to use the container directly?
Do you have any suggestion over duplication of message detection?
Happy to try to contribute to the open source project.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception extending from ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException from postProcessMessage() of DuplicateChecking MPP when message is duplicate will also not pass the message to the rabbit Listener.